# Complex Solr sorting expression in 4.0 alpha

Tags: solr

I want to perform complex sorting expression for which I have upgraded to solr-aplha 4.0:

```
apache-solr-4.0.0-BETA/select?q=*:*&sort=map(sum(SCORE,11),77,77,sum(SCORE,33),sum(SCORE,44)) desc
```

But when I try to run this, it's not working.

How can I do such complex queries of Solr?

Comment: Can you please tell us if you get any error while executing your query?

Comment: map(sum(SCORE,11),77,77,sum(SCORE,33),sum(SCORE,44)) desc is not working
while
map(sum(SCORE,11),77,77,22,33) desc is working

Comment: I got that it's not working, but could you please elaborate a bit more? Do you get an error back? DO you get wrong results? Thanks

Comment: on executing
apache-solr-4.0.0-BETA/select?q=*:*&sort=map(sum(SCORE,11),77,77,SCORE,0)%20desc i m getting error as 

sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index: map(sum(SCORE,11),77,77,SCORE,0)

Comment: Could you try replacing score with a constant and see if you still get error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using max and sub functions like:

```
max(sub(SCORE,11),0)
```